# how long is a memory address typically in bits

Tags: memory, byte, cpu-word, cpu-architecture, processor

I am confused with so many terminologies that my instructor talks about such as `word`,`byte addressing` and `memory location`.

I was under the impression that for a `32-bit processor`,
it can address upto `2^32 bits`, which is `4.29 X 10^9 bits (NOT BYTES)`.

The way I think now is:

The `memory` is like an `array` of `buckets` each of `1 byte length`.

when we say `byte addressing` (which I guess is the most common ones), each `char` is `1 byte` and is retrieved from the first bucket (say for example). 
for `int` the next `4 bytes` are put together in `little-endian ordering` to compute the `Integer` value.

so each memory, I see it as, `8 bits` or `1 byte`, which can give upto `2^8 locations`, this is far less than what `cpu` can address.

There is some very basic mis-understanding here on my part which if some experts can explain in simple terms that a prosepective CS-major student can it in once forever.

I have read various pages including this one [on word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) and here the `unit of address resolution` is given as `8b` for `ARM`, which adds more to my confusion.

Comment: Byte address*able*, not byte address*ing*.  Memory locations are 8-bits, but pointers are 32 bits (or 64 or whatever), not 8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(For a typical 32-bit processor, as posited in the question) - The processor uses 32 bits to store an address. With 32 bits, you can store 2^32 distinct numbers, ranging from 0 to 2^32 - 1. "Byte addressing" means that each byte in memory is individually addressable, i.e. there is an address *x* which points to that specific byte. Since there are 2^32 different numbers you can put into a 32-bit address, we can address up to 2^32 bytes, or 4 GB.

It sounds like the key misconception is the meaning of "byte addressing." That only means that each individual byte has its own address. Addresses themselves are still composed of multiple bytes (4, in this case, since four 8-bit bytes are taken together and interpreted as a single 32-bit number).

> I was under the impression that for a 32-bit processor, it can address upto 2^32 bits, which is 4.29 X 10^9 bits (NOT BYTES).

This is typically not the case -- bit-level addressing is quite rare. Byte addressing is far more common. You *could* design a CPU that worked this way, though. In that case as you said, you would be able to address up to 2^32 bits = 2^29 bytes (512 MiB).

Comment: I read this 3 times and each time I am understanding it better. how does the `word size` come into play here?

Comment: @eagertoLearn The "word size" is the size of the numbers that the processor operates on. When it (say) adds two numbers together, the word size is the size of those numbers. Word size is commonly, *but not always,* the same as the address size.

Comment: is there any advantage of using byte addressing. since the technology has grown so much, why the addressing has not gone up?

Comment: @eagertoLearn The advantage would be being able to address more total memory. The disadvantage is that any code that needs to deal with individual bytes becomes much more complex, since it has to separate the bytes from each addressable word. These days, with 64-bit machines allowing (currently) up to 2^44 = 16 TB (current 64-bit implementations do not use all address bits), and (eventually) up to 2^64 = 16 exabytes, there is no motivation to move away from byte addressing.

Comment: right now int takes up to 4 bytes and there is byte-ordering involved.if my memory addressing is not 1-byte not 4-bytes, I actually get access faster and with 64-bit, I could access that memory address I guess

Comment: "You could design a CPU that worked this way, though. In that case as you said, you would be able to address up to 2^32 bits = 1 GBytes"

I think it should be 512 MB (Mega Bytes):
2^32 = 4294967296 aderesses (each point to a bit);
4294967296 / 8 = 536870912 Bytes (8 bits is 1 byte);
536870912 / (1024*1024) = 512 MB.

Is this correct?

Comment: @ViníciusPJ Quite right. Well spotted - I've edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, 4Gib / (8 bits/byte) = 512MiB.  The bits cancel, leaving the units as bytes.

Comment: If only 4gb are addressable then how it is possible that we have computers with more ram than that?

Comment: @Adam Because now we have computers which use more than 32 bits for addressing.

Comment: @TypeIA sorry, I meant on 32-bit machines, and I found out it's a technique called Physical Address Extension which essentially creates a 36 bit address space

Answer (score -1):

For one bit, You would have 0 or 1 and For two bits, you would have 00, 01, 10, 11. For 8 bits, you would have 2^8 which is 256 address values. Address and Data are separate terms. Address is the location and Data is the content in that location. Data width(content) is how many bits you could store in one memory cell address.(Think like an apartment with bedrooms- each apartment *in a building* has two bedrooms)and Data depth(address) is how many addresses you would have(In a building how many apartments you would have #1 thru #1400 etc). One bit in the CPU register can reference an individual byte in memory like one number in apartment number can reference one apartment. SIMM module RAMs had 32 bit Data width and DIMM modules have 64 bit Data width. It means in one memory address in DIMM, It stores 64 bits data. How many addresses can be multiplexed by two wires (two bit processing), you could make 4 addresses. (Each of these addresses could hold 64 bits if it is DIMM module ). 32 bit processing means, 32 wires, 2^32 address options. Even though, 64 bit processing has 64 bit registers and internal bus (wires) as 64 bit, http://www.tech-faq.com/address-bus.html, address bus max is 44 bits. means 2^44 maximum addressing can be achieved by Intel Super Server CPU Itanium 2.

Comment: Even though a DIMM itself might only be word-addressable, you need a memory controller to talk to it.  The memory controller / cache is what provides byte-addressability.  (But doesn't DDR DRAM have enable / disable lines that do allow a byte store without a read-modify-write cycle in the memory controller, for uncacheable stores?)